# How to use Tube (and regionplot) for this parametric plot?

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions

```
ParametricPlot3D[{(1 + Cos[Theta]) Cos[Phi], (1 + Cos[Theta]) Sin[
Phi], Sin[Theta]}, {Theta, 0, 2 Pi}, {Phi, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

How do I use `Tube` to do exactly the same? I tried something like

```
Graphics3D[  Tube[Table[{(1 + Cos[Theta]) Cos[Phi], (1 + Cos[Theta]) Sin[Phi],     Sin[Theta]}, {Theta, 0, 2 Pi}, {Phi, 0, 2 Pi}]]]


Graphics3D[  Tube[Table[{(1 + Cos[Theta]) Cos[Phi], (1 + Cos[Theta]) Sin[Phi],     Sin[Theta]}, {Theta, 0, 2 Pi, 0.01}, {Phi, 0, 2 Pi, 0.01}]]]
```

But I feel there must be an easier way to guess the step (i.e. using 0.01? or 0.1? or something else)

What about `RegionPlot` for the same graph?

Answer (score 5):

```
pp = ParametricPlot3D[{(1 + Cos[Theta]) Cos[Phi], (1 + Cos[Theta]) Sin[Phi], Sin[Theta]}, 
 {Theta, 0, 2 Pi}, {Phi, 0, 2 Pi}, Mesh -> None]
```

[image]

```
tube = Tube[Append[#, 0] & /@ CirclePoints[100], 1];

directives = Cases[pp, {dir__, _GraphicsGroup} :> dir, All];

Graphics3D[{## & @@ directives, tube}, Axes -> True]
```

[image]